# GatsbyJS + Netlify CMS Issue with relative path

Tags: path, netlify, netlify-cms

I am trying to add new projects to my  GatsbyJS site using Netlify CMS. The problem is that my code is using relative path to reach the thumb images but when uploading a new thumb image from netlify it saves it as an absolute path. This is causing a problem and I dont understand what it is exactly. Is Gatsby not able to read the absolute path that is being received from the CMS? If that could be the problem, how could i make that the CMS gives me a relative path?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

This is the path in my markdown files:

```
thumb: ../images/thumbs/memory.png
```

This is the path created by the CMS:

```
/src/images/thumbs/img_2370.jpg
```

This is my config.yml

```
    backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master # Branch to update (optional; defaults to master)

publish_mode: editorial_workflow

media_folder: "src/images/thumbs"

collections:
  - name: "projects" # Used in routes, e.g., /admin/collections/blog
    label: "Projects" # Used in the UI
    folder: "src/projects" # The path to the folder where the documents are stored
    create: true # Allow users to create new documents in this collection
    slug: "{{slug}}" # Filename template, e.g., YYYY-MM-DD-title.md
    fields: # The fields for each document, usually in front matter
      - { label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Stack", name: "stack", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Slug", name: "slug", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Url", name: "url", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime" }
      - { label: "Thumb", name: "thumb", widget: "image" }
      - { label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "known issue" that Netlify should fix soon (it has been 2 years since it has been spotted so far). Netlify doesn't support relative paths hence the image paths are broken.

Consider using the following solutions:

- [`gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths/) adding the following in your `gatsby-config.js`:

  ```
  module.exports = {
     plugins: [

       // Including in your Gatsby plugins will transform any paths in your frontmatter
       `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths`,

       // Including in your Remark plugins will transform any paths in your markdown body
       {
         resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
         options: {
           plugins: [
             `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths`,
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
  }
  ```
- [`gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2/) by adding:

  ```
     {
       resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
       options: {
         plugins: [
           // gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2 must
           // go before gatsby-remark-images
           {
             resolve: `gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2`,
           },
           {
             resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
             options: {
               // It's important to specify the maxWidth (in pixels) of
               // the content container as this plugin uses this as the
               // base for generating different widths of each image.
               maxWidth: 590,
             },
           },
         ],
       },
     },
  ```
- Check that `media_folder` and `public_folder` are properly configured:

  ```
  media_folder: src/images/thumbs
  public_folder: /images/thumbs
  ```

  Note the starting slash in the `public_folder` and double-check that those are the correct ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Sadly still not working. I have added the new plugins. Do i need to change the query I was using?
I have also changes the config.yml to:
media_folder: "src/images/thumbs" 
public_folder: "/src/images/thumbs"

Comment: I used to use `/static` folder for the uploaded assets. I guess that assets inside `/src` folder are not transpiled via webpack into the public one because there are any usages of them. Try using `media_folder: static/assets/images public_folder: /assets/images` (and change the paths of the markdowns accordingly)

Comment: I have changed the images to be located in the static folder + adapted the config.yml, but still not working. I have adapted the path in the markdowns like this: ../../static/assets/images/countries.png
But still what is being uploaded to github looks different:
from my code: ../../static/assets/images/countries.png
from CMS: /assets/images/140.jpeg

Comment: If the images are uploaded to the `static` folder at `/static/assets/images/imageName.jpg` the CMS path should be correct since the image exist at that route

Comment: 3:13:46 PM: error Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/projects/": {
3:13:46 PM:   "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-projects-index-js",
"path": "/projects/",
"result": {
"data": {
"projects": {
"nodes": [
{
"html": "<p>testing images in the static folder</p>",
"frontmatter": {
"title": "testing images in static folderr",
"stack": "react",
"slug": "static-folder",
Creating deploy upload records
"url": "simonc.netlify.app",
"thumb": null
},
"id": "94da2cfa-4a31-5548-80e2-896e64ce8434"
},

Comment: This is the error I am getting from netlify. Somehow the image is not being uploaded when creating a new project from the CMS...